# execute file .lnk in Java

Tags: java, shell, process, command, execute

i need to execute a .lnk file in java (lnk file that points at an exe file). how can i do?

in vb .net i do

```
Process.Start(path)
```

and it works

thx you for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "C:\\temp\\file.lnk");
Process process = pb.start();
```

Call `process.getInputStream()` and `process.getErrorStream()` to read the output and error output of the process.

Comment: ok, it works!

But now i need to know what is the process's pid that i've just started. thx

Comment: If you want to ask a supplementary question it's best to edit your original question to include it.

Comment: It would be best to create a new question, because finding the pid is a completely different can of worms :)

Comment: ok, it works!

But now i need to know what is the process's pid that i've just started.
thx

Comment: @Maverick-F14: Best ask that in a *new* question.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, you could use `rundll`:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL " +  
    "\Path\to\File.lnk");
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has no support for OS specific features, but java.awt.Desktop.open should do.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use ProcessBuilder... but it will need a path to the actual rundll32.
I did it, while trying to sort an odd bug in my little "Hierarchic Send to" app.

*(I hate that windows, post-XP "flatten", the links in the "Send to" option to a stupid list; as a tree, I could navigate better the forty odd small options that I use on my system )*

Here is the code of the action calling a link (or whatever type of file):

```
ArrayList<String> app = new ArrayList<>();
app.add("C:\\Windows\\System32\\rundll32.exe");
app.add("SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL");
app.add(file.getAbsolutePath());

// Args are passed by windows when it launches the "More Sends" jar
for (int i = 0; args != null && i < args.length; i++) {
    app.add(args[i]);
}

ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder(app);
// The logger thread hangs till the called process does not die... not ideal
 // log(
    b.start()
// )
;
```

However, the whole shenhanigan of calling a windows .lnk through Java can give pretty confusing results.

A direct link to  x.jar may open the jar with the system Java VM, but a direct link to  installed jre/bin/javaw.exe -jar "x.jar" may fail, with a "Windows can't locate the file" message.

This, while  another jar called the exact same way will execute flawessly.

Though, I might have to look at the alternate streams of the .lnk, as some are copies from my old PC...