# Open shortcut (.lnk) with parameter lines Java

Tags: java, parameter-passing, lnk

I'd like to start a shortcut with parameter-lines How could I execute this shortcut with parameters in Java? (As this doesn't work with ProcessBuilder I'm stuck once again...)

**"C:/Program Files/MyPrograms/MyShortcut.lnk" -s 3 -n 100** (what ever these parameter lines mean now)

I'm sucessfully able to launch my shortcut, without parameters.

code:

```
String directoryFile = "C:/Program Files/MyPrograms/MyShortcut.lnk"

Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(directoryFile));
```

What I want:

```
String directoryFile = "C:/Program Files/MyPrograms/MyShortcut.lnk"

Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(directoryFile)+"-s 3 -n 100");
```

This does work, but only for .exe files; I'd need to open a .lnk(win shortcut) with parameters

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Program Files/MyPrograms/MyFile.exe",
                                          "-n", "100")
                                      .start();
```

Thanks

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749660/execute-file-lnk-in-java it does in fact work.

Comment: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to decode the LNK to get the actual EXE path/file.

See: [Windows shortcut (.lnk) parser in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309495/windows-shortcut-lnk-parser-in-java)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much.

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "C:\\path\\shortcut.lnk", "-n", "100");
        Process process = pb.start();

Answer (score 4):

If someone is looking for the same thing, this worked like a charm! (thanks to 'Glenn Lane' for linking me)

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "C:\\path\\shortcut.lnk", "-n", "100"); Process process = pb.start();
```